# Can lifetime of objects in a initializer list be extended?

Tags: c++, c++11, lifetime, initializer-list, const-reference

I have the impression that `std::initializer_list` might behave like literal strings in C++, and even further they might extend the lifetime of const references. Is that a correct assessment?

**Can objects in an `initializer_list` be somehow *referenced* later (without copying them), in local scope? in global scope?**

For example this tests pass in GCC and clang. 
Is that just fortuitous?

```
#include<cassert>
#include<initializer_list> 
struct A{
    double const* p;
    A(std::initializer_list<double> il){ p = &*(il.begin() + 1); };
};
double f(){return 5.;}
int main(){
   A a1{1.,2.,3.};
   assert( *a1.p == 2. );
   A a2{1., f(), f()};
   assert( *a2.p == 5. );
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is undefined behaviour.

In your case `initializer_list` refers to temporary array `const double[3]`, the lifetime of this array is described as below:

> [ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)
>   The underlying array is not guaranteed to exist after the lifetime of
>   the original initializer list object has ended. [until c++14]
>
> The lifetime of the underlying array is the same as any other
>   temporary object [since c++14]

and

> [ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime) All temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the
>   full-expression

so in your case when constructor of `A` is called, temporary array with 3 doubles is created, then you are taking address of elements of temporary array and when constructor ends temporary array is destroyed (in this case the full expression is the call of ctor), so as a result `p` is dangling poiner.

Comment: Thank you. I don't see why this cannot be made a standard behavior, especially in the first case and for POD types. In wouldn't be too different from `char const* p = "hello"; assert(p[1] == 'e')`. The second case is more tricky.